# C# how would i get all the names of the childNodes from a treeview

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello could someone show me how would i get the name of all the child nodes in a tree view the below code shows how i get the name of the tree view i selected now how would i get all the child node names of the tree view i selected from a tree view list that i selected and store the names of all the child nodes that are in a tree in a variable

```
private void TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Node.FullPath);
            selectedNode = e.Node.FullPath;
           
            
        }
```

Comment: yes its a windows form application and visual studio is what im using to code it in

Comment: Okay, so even if you're using Visual Studio, that doesn't mean it's relevant to the question. That doesn't change anything. You should only use that tag if you actually have a question about using Visual Studio itself. You should also tag the appropriate framework you're working in (Windows Forms) so that your question is seen by the right people. I saw you originally tagged this question as C++ as well - please don't tag it if it's not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Example in VB:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick

    GetChildNodes(e.Node)

End Sub

Private Sub GetChildNodes(N As TreeNode)

    For Each nChild As TreeNode In N.Nodes

        Debug.Print(nChild.FullPath)

        If nChild.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            GetChildNodes(nChild)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```